# Run method before opening contextmenu Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have an application where, when I right click on an element, a contextmenu should open. On the right click, it should also highlight my selected element. Selecting the element is already done in another method called `Form1_MouseClick`.
What I want is that before the contextmenu is opened, my application should run the Form1_MouseClick method, since I click with my mouse. This, however, does not happen.

Do you have a solution to this problem that does not involve the `MouseUp` or `MouseDown` button? Had complications with doubleclicking etc. with those methods, so we decided to use MouseClick and MouseDoubleClick.

Comment: Some elements do not raise the right click event.Maybe this link can help you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/mouse-events-in-windows-forms

Comment: You can use [Popup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenu.popup(v=vs.110).aspx) event of menu, it is rised before menu is displayed.